# How to post json object in Xcode 4?

Tags: ios, ios4, xcode4

i am getting my json object using asynchronous nsurl connection as
`{"firstname":"A","Contact":{"phone":1234567899,"email":"abc@yahoo.com"}}`

I want to know that if i change the value of my phone number and then want to upload it back, how i can do that. Do we have to send only key-value pair for phone or entire object
{"firstname":"A","Contact":{"phone":1234567899,"email":"abc@yahoo.com"}} with updated phone number to server for updating in database.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]; [request setURL:myUrl];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:stringInNSData];
```

I have found the above logic almost everywhere but don't know how to implement and where to implement.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on your server and how the database is stored.  If you are using an SQL like database, you will need to pass the primary key that identifies what data row you want to update along with the updated fields.  The server code that receives the post can update the attributes you pass in and leave the rest of the data row alone.

For where to implement this, you should implement it whenever your data changes.  If there are UI elements that are triggering the data change, you can implement it there.  Just add this below your code

```
NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

That will set the class that the code is implemented in as the delegate for the connection and start the connection. You can use these methods to handle the success or failure of your update.

```
Connection Data and Responses
– connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:  delegate method Available in iOS 3.0 through iOS 4.3
– connection:didReceiveData:  delegate method Available in iOS 2.0 through iOS 4.3
– connection:didReceiveResponse:  delegate method Available in iOS 2.0 through iOS 4.3
– connection:willCacheResponse:  delegate method Available in iOS 2.0 through iOS 4.3
– connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:  delegate method Available in iOS 2.0 through iOS 4.3
Connection Completion
– connection:didFailWithError:  delegate method Available in iOS 2.0 through iOS 4.3
– connectionDidFinishLoading:  delegate method Available in iOS 2.0 through iOS 4.3
```

Comment: yes, it is :-) I am making an app just like online product rating. Now i am again stuck up in it.I am accessing all the comments which users have posted.i have putted in a tableview but there's a problem like if the the size of text is larger, and the tableview cell only shows 1 line. I am looking for how to resize the height of a tableview.

Comment: I got this in viewDidLoad ->
 myTableViewTwo = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    myTableViewTwo.dataSource = self;
    myTableViewTwo.delegate = self;          
    [self.view addSubview: myTableViewTwo];

Comment: and and - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    jsonDetailData = [responseString JSONValue];
    CGSize size = [[jsonDetailData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                   sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]
                   constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300,500)];
    return size.height + 10;
}

Comment: But i am getting "SIGABRT" in "constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300,500)"
with error log in console == -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c79540
2011-11-05 10:25:29.396 InstructorReview[851:bc03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4c79540'

Comment: Your jsonDetailData object is really a dictionary.  [__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:] is causing the exception.  Before you get further into displaying the data, you should play around with log statements and see how to access all of the data that is returned from the json string.  Also, you should ask new questions, not start a new question in a comment change.  It would be ok if it was related to answering the first question.